# CSS - How can I center a <script>'s output?

Tags: html, css

I've been having a lot of trouble trying to center an external script and I was hoping SO could help me out.  I'm designing a page to use a Google widget that uses Google Maps to give directions to an office.  Here is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="page_content" runat="server">
<div class="centered">

<span class="header_large_bold">Directions to our office:</span><br /><br />

<span class="header_bold">Please type your address in the top bar and click "Go".</span><br />

<script src="[link to the widget here]"</script>

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the CSS for it:

```
.centered {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

As it is, the text is centered perfectly fine, but the widget from the  is left aligned.  I can fix this using a  tag, but I'm trying to avoid using it as best I can.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Depends on the markup being generated by the script.

Comment: A <script> probably contains JS code. You want to center the elements the JS is generating. Could you please share the code being output?

Comment: You don't center a script. The script generates HTML/CSS. The generated stuff is what you want to center.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the  tag in a div

```
<div id="parent">
    <script src='...'></script>
</div>
```

and then center the div..

```
#parent {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**But it might depend on the script content**

Comment: But their content can be centered, if inserted in a div (parent)

Answer (score 1):

Easily put your code between

```
<div align=center>
```

and

```
</div>
```

:)

Answer (score -2):

User fa7d0 has the exact solution, but maybe a little unclear for the beginner:

Step 1 - Use a div with a "parent" ID to encapsulate your script as follows:

```
<div id="parent">
<script src='...'></script>
</div>
```

Step 2 - Go up to the top of your code, probably inside the area where you are defining the header information, and in the style section place the definitions:

```
<style>
#parent {
width: 30%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

I find it helpful to put all the div styling stuff in one area, all the p styling stuff in one area, etc.